# Running @Scheduled without waiting previous task to get completed

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading, asynchronous, schedule

I am using `@Scheduled` with `fixedRate`.
This job scans the db and put the data to second DB.

So my question is, if my one task is running and have exceeded over 10 mins, the next task is waiting for previous task. I want the behaviour that will not wait for the previous task to terminate or complete its task.

Can someone help on this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code which I wrote for scheduling.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    public void scanDB() {
        // Scans DB 
        // Puts in new DB
    }
```

Comment: Even with `fixedRate`, the scheduler doesn't allow parallel runs of the job. The duplicate contains a solution by using `@EnableAsync` and `@Async`.